# Adding an animation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an sticky element that I want to animate when it becomes relative and viceversa.

This is the code I have:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

 if ($(this).scrollTop() + windowHeight >= windowPosition + 200) {
   $('.sticky-footer').css({'position':'relative', 'background':'#fff'});
   $('.when-sticky').css('display', 'none');
   $('.no-sticky').css('display', 'block');

 } else if (windowPosition >= $(this).scrollTop()) {
   $('.sticky-footer').css({'position':'fixed', 'background':'#eee'});
   $('.when-sticky').css('display', 'block');
   $('.no-sticky').css('display', 'none');
 }
})
```

What can I do in order to animate it on this 2 parts:

```
$('.sticky-footer').css({'position':'relative', 'background':'#fff'});
```

and

```
$('.sticky-footer').css({'position':'fixed', 'background':'#eee'});
```

Comment: Why not use `jQuery.animate()`?

Comment: @Anson I can't adapt it to my code :/

Comment: You can't animate color with jQuery it self... you will need some plugin, or you can use CSS animations.